# In linux, if I change hostname with the public IP, the request targeted the IP would be caused Internal traffic?

Tags: linux, networking

What I want to know is the traffic of local machine which was occurred its own hostname.

For example,
if I set the local hostname into abc.com,
then set some application to send the request to that abc.com hostname,
the request would be returned before being sent to outside of the network card?
or just move out into the gateway and turn back.
(I supposed that the machine is under the Access Pointer with private IP,
and the IP set the hostname was Public IP that AP has.)

Somebody can explain exactly what will be happened?

Thanks-

Comment: Data routing doesn't care about hostnames, it works only with IPs. Applications translate the name to an IP before calling the functions that send data.

Comment: Is your question about what happens if you have a machine behind a NAT router, and it tries to send to its public IP instead of its private IP? It depends on the router. Some routers will reflect it back, some only perform port forwarding when the traffic comes from outside.

Comment: Question is unclear and badly worded.

Answer (score 0):

Self answering.
My question was not clear so apologise it.

Question was how to loop back on the machine with its public IP, locally.
This happening would be supposed by VM environment such as Amazone  or whatever.
The machine in the cloud knows only its private IP, so if some application in the machine try to connect to itself with the public IP, the Network would be passed to Gateway and turning back to itself.
In this case, my concern was it was 'Network traffic' as well, so speed would be not as fast as loop back IP (127.0.0.1).

=============

And I found some solution with ifconfig loopback alias.
You can use this with any IP working as loopback IP, on the machine.

```
sudo ifconfig lo:1 inet <TargetIpAddress> netmask 255.255.255.255 up
```

The network will loop back all traffic occurred by that IP.
(Be sure that set the netmask carefully, because if you set 255.0.0.0, it will loop back all of your targetIpAdress accepted according to that mask.

==============

Sorry to get confused with terrible question again,
but I left this for someone who has stupid questions like me.

Thanks.